# htaccess 301 redirect doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Live site- http://www.marchingmonk.com

I add 301 redirect on my htaccess file but that doesn't not work.
Code-

```
Redirect 301 /home http://www.marchingmonk.com
```

When you click on the "home" button of the website, the user is not being redirected to http://www.marchingmonk.com, the user is redirected to http://www.marchingmonk.com/home, this creating a duplicate content issue. That site is created with a CMS(i don't have any knowledge on that CMS), so i want to make a redirection by htaccess file but that not works.

Any idea how to fix that issue.

Full code of htaccess file-

```
#old php Handler

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^marchingmonk\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.marchingmonk.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?marchingmonk.com$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/home/?$ http://www.marchingmonk.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch` for its regex capabilities:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/?$ http://www.marchingmonk.com/? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^marchingmonk\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?marchingmonk\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Not to show- http://www.marchingmonk.com/?id=home when click on home button on menu

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the duty/role of last 2 line of code.

Comment: Last 2 lines are from your existing code. This rule forwards any non-file non-directory request to `/index.php` with GET parameter `'id'`

Comment: I know that is come from previous code, i was just curious about the role of it. Thank you so much.